# How do I sync my development on multiple computers?

Tags: git, svn

I write most of my PHP on one computer, but would like to edit it on my laptop while in bed on occasion.

I imagine SVN or GIT would be a good candidate for this, or perhaps there's a better alternative.

Is there someone out there who has tested many configurations, and found the most effective/efficient with current technology?

I do most of my work on my Win7 desktop and laptop, but am open to working with ubuntu. I use eclipse 3.7 with PDT 3.0

I don't use the wamp package, and have mysql/php/apache installed separately. I also have a filezilla server for sending files between the two machines.

I have tried setting up SVN - but find that I forget to do updates/commits with tortoise. Maybe I should set up a windows script to remember for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use git.  It provides tools that can really help you.

I'd suggest you combine that with an easy syncing tool to ensure you have all the files you want with you on whatever machine you want to work.

For instance, I write all my code within my free Dropbox folder.  I also use git and push to github.  This gives me version control and convenient access to my code from Linux @ work, Win7/Ubuntu on my home desktop and Win7/Ubuntu on my laptop.  It really makes my life easier because it doesn't matter where, or which OS I've booted, I can always access my code and work on it when an idea strikes me.

Answer (score 1):

I would very strongly recommend Git or Mercurial. Forget SVN. It requires you to run a central server and is far from ideal in this configuration. If you are running Ubuntu you need nothing more than SSH access between machines and Git or Mercurial will work fine for you out of the box.

I'm not sure about how to host a Git repo on windows. Mercurial ships with a built-in server where you simply `hg serve` (or the tortoise equivalent) and you have a server up instantly ready for pulls.

As for forgetting to commit things you need to simply remember to do it. Having a script auto-commit for you makes history tracking a bit difficult. You need to commit when you've completed a logical unit of code. I'm going to assume you are not a professional developer from this and recommend you get in to the habit of committing by yourself. If you ever plan to work on a team they will expect your commits to make sense.

Comment: My understanding is that Git is more widely used in the corporate environment - would my time be better spent learning it vs mercurial? It would be nice to kill two pigs with one bird

Comment: They are both relatively widely used but Git has a more complex interface and tends to be more popular among some open source projects (especially PHP ones). It doesn't really matter which you learn. It won't take too much effort to switch to the other.

Comment: Even if you forget to commit, if you have SSH access to the offending machine, you can just log in, commit, and push. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using a Source Control system such as Git.

[GitHub](https://www.github.com/) allows free, public repositories (or cheap private ones) and practically holds your hand in setting it up. It is dead simple to use on Ubuntu, and can integrate with Cygwin on Windows or the Windows Shell with [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).